# Changing color of footnotes in Chicago-Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, color, footnotes, biblatex-chicago

I'm quite new to Latex in general, and I'm trying to write a document using Chicago style citation. I have used the package Chicago-Biblatex to try to achieve this.

At the moment, everything is working well, and I am using \autocite for each footnote. However, I have two footnotes referencing the same citation, and the first footnote is the full citation, and the second footnote is an abbreviated footnote.

The abbreviated footnote is in blue since it is clickable in the PDF (bringing you to the first footnote). I would like to make this abbreviated footnote in black and non-italicized and to remove the hyperlink if possible.

Here is the original, full length citation:
[image: Original, full length citation]

Here is the shortened citation that I want to make normal text (non-italicized), and black
[image: Shortened citation with different color]

Code:

```
 % !TEX TS–program = pdflatexmk

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{ftnxtra}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\newcommand*{\footnotemarkcolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{%
   \color{\footnotemarkcolor}\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{mybib.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,
   unpublished,techreport,misc,book]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
 
\begin{document}

\section{Part 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at metus id ante hendrerit bibendum eget eu sapien.\autocite{citation1} Donec elit odio, placerat luctus turpis at, lobortis mollis massa.\autocite{citation2}


\section{Part 2}
Phasellus volutpat non urna eget imperdiet. Curabitur commodo eros sit amet odio facilisis efficitur. Nulla varius efficitur viverra. Morbi bibendum libero sit amet est euismod dignissim ut vitae odio. Sed sodales ante neque, eu condimentum velit varius ut. Donec pretium ullamcorper tincidunt.\autocite{citation1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

mybib.bib code:

```
@misc{citation1,
    author = {Wikipedia},
    title = {Iniesta (footballer, born 1992)},
    month = 01,
    year = 2020,
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Iniesta_(footballer,_born_1992)&oldid=983077102},
    urldate = {2019-02-05},
    note = "Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia"
  }

@misc{citation2,
    author = {Wikipedia},
    title = {Messi (footballer, born 1987)},
    month = 02,
    year = 2020,
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi},
    urldate = {2019-02-05},
    note = "Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field format that is used for those short citations is called `citetitle`, so I just used the same format you set for `title` also for `citetitle`, but you can change that as you wish.

We can disable the links `biblatex-chicago` produces for citations by disabling the macro `\cmshyper`. (Though I wouldn't do that, those links are really convenient.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ftnxtra}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}

\newcommand*{\footnotemarkcolor}{black}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{%
   \color{\footnotemarkcolor}\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,
   unpublished,techreport,misc,book]
  {title}{\mkbibquote{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,
   unpublished,techreport,misc,book]
  {citetitle}{\mkbibquote{#1}}

\renewrobustcmd*{\cmshyper}[1]{#1}%
 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{citation1,
    author = {Wikipedia},
    title = {Iniesta (footballer, born 1992)},
    month = 01,
    year = 2020,
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Iniesta_(footballer,_born_1992)&oldid=983077102},
    urldate = {2019-02-05},
    note = "Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia"
  }
@misc{citation2,
    author = {Wikipedia},
    title = {Messi (footballer, born 1987)},
    month = 02,
    year = 2020,
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lionel_Messi},
    urldate = {2019-02-05},
    note = "Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia"
  }
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Part 1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus at metus id ante hendrerit bibendum eget eu sapien.\autocite{citation1} Donec elit odio, placerat luctus turpis at, lobortis mollis massa.\autocite{citation2}

\section{Part 2}
Phasellus volutpat non urna eget imperdiet. Curabitur commodo eros sit amet odio facilisis efficitur. Nulla varius efficitur viverra. Morbi bibendum libero sit amet est euismod dignissim ut vitae odio. Sed sodales ante neque, eu condimentum velit varius ut. Donec pretium ullamcorper tincidunt.\autocite{citation1}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Wikipedia, “Iniesta (footballer, born 1992).”]

Comment: Hey, thanks very much! The only problem when trying to use your code is that I get the error code: "Package etoolbox Error: \cmshyper undefined".

Comment: @10forever Are you using an older version of `biblatex-chicago`? I'm using the current version that identifies as `2020/04/20 v 3.14` in the `.log` file and Version 2.0 (April 20, 2020) in the documentation. You may want to update your TeX system.

Comment: Perfect! That was the problem. Thanks very much again for the help.